# Getting all Employees under a Manager C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, recursion

I am trying to a list of all of the employees that are under a manager in a table. So a manager can go to a webpage and view every single person that is under him/her including all hierarchies.

An Employee consists of this:

```
public class Employee
{
     int id {get; set;}
     string FirstName {get; set;}
     string LastName {get; set;}
     int EmployeeNumber {get; set;}
     int ManagerEmployeeNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Currently, I am just getting a a managers direct reports but I want to show every single person that under a manager.

Example:

```
(FirstName: "Aaron", EmployeeNumber: 1, ManagerEmployeeNo: NULL)
(FirstName: "Jack", EmployeeNumber: 2, ManagerEmployeeNo: 1)
(FirstName: "Roger", EmployeeNumber: 3, ManagerEmployeeNo: 1)
(FirstName: "Nat", EmployeeNumber: 4, ManagerEmployeeNo: 2)
(FirstName: "Fred", EmployeeNumber: 4, ManagerEmployeeNo: 4)
```

This is just an example and managers can go a lot deeper than this.

This is what I currently have:

```
public List<Employee> GetManagedEmployees(Employee manager)
{
    var managedEmployees =_employeeDb.Employees.Where(e => e.ManagerEmployeeNumber == manager.EmployeeNumber).ToList();

    return managedEmployees.Any() == false ? null : managedEmployees;
}
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a homework for school?

Comment: @SQLPolice No, it is not

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with `SQL` or with `LINQ`?

Comment: @RickS They are both fine. I would prefer LINQ but i dont mind using a stored procedure to load the data either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a flat list then this is simple recursion.  In pseudo-code, it would look like this:

```
IList<Employee> GetEmployees(Employee manager)
{
    var result = new List<Employee>();

    var employees = _employeeDb.Employees
                               .Where(e => e.ManagerEmployeeNumber == manager.EmployeeNumber)
                               .ToList();

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        result.Add(employee);
        result.AddRange(GetEmployees(employee));
    }

    return result;
}
```

There are certainly more *performant* approaches you could take, but for simplicity if you just want to recurse over the tree this would do the trick.  You may want to add some checks for data problems, such as ensuring there are no infinite recursions (if somehow two employees manage to report to each other... it sounds weird, but weird things happen in large companies).

If you *really* want something performant, you can do the recursion directly in SQL with [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).  It's been a while since I've used that, so I don't have an example handy.  But it's a pretty neat feature of modern SQL Server instances which *does* allow for recursion in a query.

Comment: You don't need to use `.ToList()`, and it should be faster if you don't.

Comment: @EBrown You need to if you are return IList

Comment: @EBrown: Is it really going to make a difference?  The collection is being materialized in the very next block of code anyway.  And the performance hit is in the recursive calls to the database, not in when the collection is materialized.

Comment: @Blam He doesn't actually return that query, so there's no need for it. He enumerates it in the `foreach` but merely adds each employee to a `result` list.

Comment: @David It's merely a suggestion, if you're going to use LINQ you don't need to use `.ToList()`. It's redundant and if the collection ever gets huge, it will begin to have performance impacts, as you enumerate the same values twice. You don't *have* to change it, it's your code. Merely offering a suggestion that would help ease the readability and performance of it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL databases are not particularly good at representing hierarchies (although some offer proprietary extensions, e.g. [Oracle Hierarchial Query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)).

You will need to recursively load each level of your hierarchy.  Start by getting the immediate reports as you do now.  For each of the immediate reports, you will need to then load their reports, and so on until nobody has additional reports.

Your current code structure is a good starting point.  You would recursively call GetManagedEmployees() for each subordinate, and incorporate the result of that call into the list of direct and indirect reports for the manager producing the report.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head (I haven't tested for performance) this is how I'd do it in SQL SERVER 2008 or 2012.

```
    DECLARE @allReports TABLE (employeeId int, managerEmployeeId int null);
--Insert all the top-level managers first.
INSERT INTO @allReports(employeeId,employeeManagerId)
SELECT employeeNumber,managerEmployeeNumber from employees where managerEmployeeNumber is null;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT EmployeeNumber,ManagerEmployeeNumber  from employees where ManagerEmployeeNumber IS IN (SELECT employeeNumber from @allReports);
BEGIN
Insert into @allReports(employeeId,employeeManagerId)
select e.employeeNumber, e.EmployeeManagerNumber from  employees e inner join @allReports a on e.EmployeeManagerNumber =a.employeeNumber 
where e.managerEmployeeNumber IS NOT NULL
END
```